# Top does not satisfy the axiom of choice

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am trying to think about the axiom of choice from a categorical point of view.
I found out in some book that one possible formalization of this axiom is obtained by stating: "a category $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies the axiom of choice if all epics in $\mathcal{C}$ are split".
In this way $\mathbf{Set}$ does satisfy the axiom of choice (and that is fine). The category of groups doesn't though! What about $\mathbf{Top}$, i.e. the category of topological spaces? Does a not split epimorphism exist in $\mathbf{Top}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most epimorphisms in $\mathbf{Top}$ do not split.  For instance, let $Y$ be any nondiscrete topological space and let $X$ be the underlying set of $Y$ with the discrete topology.  Then the identity map $X\to Y$ is epic but does not split (since the identity $Y\to X$ is not continuous).  There are many many many other examples; I encourage you to try coming up with some on your own.

Answer (score 4):

Top indeed does not satisfy the axiom of choice. To show this it suffices to exhibit a fiber bundle without a section, and for example the unit tangent bundle of $S^2$ has this property by the hairy ball theorem. Various other kinds of examples are possible; see, for example, [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/topological-diophantine-equations/).